# use an anchor/link element to open a particular page, and automatically open a modal on that page

Tags: javascript, html

I have both login and registration modals on my home page. These exist on a  element which is present on all pages. I would like to set the anchor elements for login/registration on the non-home pages to open the home page with the modal to automatically open.

By default there display property is set to none when you open the page, I just wanted to create links to these pages and automatically open the modals? Is there a way to use JS to do this?

Any know how would be grand, thank you.

Comment: Yes there is, please provide code for us to work with.

Comment: call model open method in onload function of pages

Comment: onload is the one, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript way: inspect the URL using [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for something that indicates which modal should open (e.g. `?modal=login`), and open that modal.

The CSS way: if each modal has a unique ID, you could use [the `:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to apply `display: block;` (or whatever) to the element when indicated in the URL fragment (so your link would have `#login` or `#registration` at the end).